# mat-table showing header columns but not rows

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, datasource, mat-table

I am dynamically loading a mat-table by doing the following:

```
<mat-table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let col of dispColumns" matColumnDef="{{col}}">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{col}}</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element ">
            {{element[col]}}
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="dispColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: dispColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 50, 100]" showFirstLastButtons
   aria-label="Select page of query data">
</mat-paginator>
```

and I am able to see the header columns. However, I don't see the rest of the data in the table. It shows the number of rows based on the `dataSource` length but it doesn't seem to output the actual metadata? How can I fix this issue?

This is how my component looks like:

```
export class Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private store: Store,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  get dataSource() {
    return this.store.dataSource;
  }
}
```

You can see that I am reading the `dataSource` from the store, which looks like this:

```
public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);
```

and then I set the `dataSource` in a different file like this:

```
this.store.dataSource = data;
```

Am I doing something worng? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you attach sample data?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out the issue and it turns out it was because `col` wasn't mapping right, which is why it displayed an empty table :-)

Comment: I had this same error, but this is not a very useful answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element ">
            {{element[col]}}
        </mat-cell>
```

you dont have a data ,let element of data

Comment: sorry ' i think a other idea

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 <mat-table mat-table>
</mat-table>
```

to-

```
<table mat-table ..>
....
</table>
```

Successes:)!